# Regarding Push Notification and Apple Development Licence

Tags: ios, iphone, sql-server, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I would like to ask about notifications and apple development license.  In addition to adding users to our shared backend on server, we will also be installing the system on user internal networks, in dedicated self-hosted implementations.  In such a scenario, how is the installation of the Push Notification system affected, versus our current installation on the platform?  Can we install multiple servers, each with its respective notification systems running concurrently at different user sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can have many servers sending push notifications - there is no problem with that. You would need to handle centralized or distributed database of the users devices IDs (to which you want to send notifications), so you don't end up sending same notifications to the same device from your multiple servers multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If by `installing the system on user internal networks` you mean networks not connected to the internet, then you can't use Apple Push Notifications, since it requires access to Apple's servers.

If, however, you simply mean that multiple servers connected to the internet would send push notifications to your app, you can do it. I assume you'd want each subset of devices that install your app to send their device tokens to a different server, which will send push notifications to those devices. Each server would need your push certificate in order to send notifications to your app. You can either share the same certificate with all servers that host your server code, or create a different certificate for each server.